# debugging asp + silverlight app in IIS 5.1

Tags: silverlight, debugging, iis

I'm having trouble debugging my asp+silverlight app on IIS 5.1. I tried to follow some tutorials, but with no result. Here it's what I've tried:

- Check "Enable ASP server-side script debugging" for my websites, on IIS Manager
- Set some breakpoints
- Attach aspnet_wp.exe to my solution

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I want to be able to debug server side code (webservices)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an old version of IIS? If this is just because of what you've got on your dev machine, can you use Cassini instead? Surely you're not intending to *deploy* on IIS 5.1, right?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, it is ASP.NET. @Ken - I'll give it a try. It is what I have on dev machine. Anyway, i've managed to debug the application already. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to fiddle with "Enable ASP server-side script debugging" to debug ASP.NET, that setting relates to the older script based ASP.

You are correct you need to attached to the aspnet_wp in Visual Studio.  What is important to remember is that the Visual Studio can debug a range of different "Code Type".  I prefer to control this manually.  When attaching use the "Select..." button next to the "Attach to:" box and select "Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0)" option.

You should now be able to debugging your ASP.NET and use break points.